# Accessing Google APIs from iPhone native app

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, gdata

I'd like to access some Google API's from within an iPhone native app. I'm not a web programmer and have never used AJAX, but I'm guessing I need some kind of bridge between Objective-C and Javascript. Ideally I'd just fire XML at Google and process the result.

I really have no idea were to start.

Has anyone successfully done this, or know of any good resources?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See gdata-objectivec-client : the official Objective-C client library for Google Data API's (it works on the iPhone too.) See http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/.
Unless you mean the AJAX Search API - see http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/#fonje - that will provide a JSON response.

Comment: The data api link was what I needed (woo! it even supports iPhone). Thanks for your response.